# Android: FingerPaint Eraser Function

Tags: android, path, paint, erase

I'm trying to implement a erase function on the Fingerpaint App in the Api Demo's in Android. I change some code based on my needs. At first the erase function works well. I used:

```
drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

It works well when the path has been drawn in the bitmap. But when I implement the Undo and Redo function(the way I achieve it is by using two arraylist and save the path there), PorterDuffXfermode doesn't work. Please take a look at this:

[image]

At image 1 I draw some paths(stored in an arraylist. Not drawn in the bitmap canvas)
Then at 2 thats the time I pressed the erase icon. I dont know what causing all the paths to became black. Then at 3 I tried to erase the paths I made(PorterDuffXFermode some says its black). Then when I switch back to drawing mode. It seems that instead or erasing, all it did was draw another path.

Any solutions for this? or workarounds? 
Here is the code when to my drawingClass:

```
//this is where the drawing takes place
public class DrawingClass extends View{
//drawing path
private Path drawPath;
//drawing and canvas paint
private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
//initial color
private int paintColor = 0xFF660000;
//canvas
private Canvas drawCanvas;
//canvas bitmap
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
private float brushSize,lastBrushSize;
private boolean erase = false;
//array list for paths
private ArrayList<PathPoints> paths = new ArrayList<PathPoints>();
private ArrayList<PathPoints> undonePaths = new ArrayList<PathPoints>();

public Context context;


private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;


public DrawingClass(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.context = context;
    setupDrawing();
}

private void setupDrawing(){
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

//instantiate the variable to get the last brush size
    brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
    lastBrushSize = brushSize;
//get drawing area setup for interaction
    drawCanvas = new Canvas();
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    //initial properties
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

    //paths.add(new PathPoints(drawPath, paintColor, brushSize));

}

public void setBrushSize(float newSize){
    //update brush size
    float pixelAmount = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            newSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    brushSize = pixelAmount;
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    invalidate();
}

public void setLastBrushSize(float lastSize){
    //set the last brush size
    lastBrushSize = lastSize;
    invalidate();
}

public float getLastBrushSize(){
    //return the last brush size
    return lastBrushSize;
}

public void setErase(boolean isErase){
    //set erase true or false
    erase = isErase;
    if (erase) {
        //drawPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    }
    else drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
}

public void startNew(){
    //creates a new canvass
    drawCanvas.drawColor(0,PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    drawCanvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    String imgSaved = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
          context.getContentResolver(), getDrawingCache(),
            UUID.randomUUID().toString()+".png", "drawing");
    destroyDrawingCache();
    paths.clear();
    undonePaths.clear();
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w,int h,int oldw,int oldh){
    //view given size
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    //draw view
    //save the strokes in the bitmap
    //canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);

    for (PathPoints p : paths){
        drawPaint.setColor(p.getColor());
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(p.getBrush());
        invalidate();
        canvas.drawPath(p.getPath(), drawPaint);
    }
}

private void touch_start(float x, float y){
    drawPath.reset();
    drawPath.moveTo(x, (float) (y+.1));
    drawPath.lineTo(x, y);
    drawPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y){
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            drawPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y+ mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
}

private void touch_up(){
    drawPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    drawPath = new Path();
    paths.add(new PathPoints(drawPath, paintColor, brushSize));
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    //detect user touch
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        invalidate();
        touch_start(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        invalidate();
        touch_move(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        invalidate();
        touch_up();
        drawPath.reset();
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

public void undoPath(){
    if (paths.size()>0) {
        undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
    } else {
        Log.d("Undo", "No paths left");
    }
    invalidate();
}

public void redoPath(){
    if (undonePaths.size()>0) {
        paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size()-1));
    } else {
        Log.d("Redo", "No paths left");
    }
    invalidate();
}


public void setColor(String newColor){
    //set color
    paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    invalidate();
}

class PathPoints{
    private Path path;
    private int color;
    private float brushsize;
    private int x, y;

    //holds the paths data
    public PathPoints(Path path, int color, float brushsize) {
        this.path = path;
        this.color = color;
        this.brushsize = brushsize;
    }

    public Path getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(Path path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public float getBrush(){
        return brushsize;
    }

    public void setBrush(float brushsize){
        this.brushsize = brushsize;
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

}

}
```